# How to search a certain value and copy the results to other sheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a VBA code.
I have 2 worksheets in excel:

First Sheet: "Results for init" that contain all my work results

Second Sheet: "Result tab"

I'm trying to find certain value in first row called `Id` ,find two certain ID numbers (86 and 66) in `Id` column and copy results (that located two columns from right) to the second sheet in a specific cells.

[image: example]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Look into the built-in function named `VLOOKUP` that does exactly this job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet
    Dim srcLR As Long, destLR As Long
    Dim cel As Range, srcRng As Range

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Results for init")
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result Tab")

    With srcSht
        srcLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row  'get last row with data in srcSht using Column C
        Set srcRng = .Range("C2:E" & srcLR)             'set range for look up
    End With

    With destSht
        destLR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'get last row with data in destSht using Column A

        For Each cel In .Range("A2:A" & destLR)         'loop through each cell in Column a of destSht
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cel, srcRng, 3, False)   'get vlookup result
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

***Solution using formula :***

Assuming your data is in sheet `Results for init` then in `Cell B2` of sheet `Result tab` enter the following formula

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Results for init'!$C$2:$E$10,3,FALSE)
```

or

```
=INDEX('Results for init'!$E$2:$E$10,MATCH(Sheet3!A2,'Results for init'!$C$2:$C$10,0))
```

Drag/Copy down formula as required. Change ranges `2:10` as per your data. See image for reference.

*Result tab* Sheet

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting run time error 1004: Unable to get the Vlookup property of the WorkSheetFunction class

Comment: @Timor - I've tested the code before posting, should work. Can you check the value of `cel` when error occurs and also of `srcRng.Address`