# VBA Repeating Search of delimited column and printing values to new line

Tags: excel, vba

Long time, first time. Painfully new to VBA and have learned a lot of info thus far from here.
I have a Workbook that has multiple sheets which is sourced from different applications and I am trying to tie it all together.

I am struggling to repeatedly search through a second sheet and print the first two columns where a matching result was found in the third column to a new line in a new sheet. It doesnt have to be a new sheet necessarily. A similar goal was discussed here ([Excel VBA Search for a value in a column and copy row to new sheet for all matching values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32138287/excel-vba-search-for-a-value-in-a-column-and-copy-row-to-new-sheet-for-all-match)) and ([How to search a certain value and copy the results to other sheet with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46401543/how-to-search-a-certain-value-and-copy-the-results-to-other-sheet-with-vba)) and plenty of others.

The two sheets only have the 'Item List' column shared between them, the second data sheet has information that I need to pull in.

First sheet is used as the main sheet in this workbook which will be doing a lot of index/matches against other sheets. This first sheet contains my search term in the first column, this search term appears in the second sheet in a column that has csv.

```
First Sheet
Item List | Sheet2.Num | Sheet2.Value | Sheet3.Length | Sheet3.Width | Sheet4.Hight | Sheet4.Volum
ItemA     | 123        | Solid        | 15cm          | 23cm         | 9cm          | 3105 cm3
ItemB     | 123        | Solid        | 6cm           | 2cm          | 5cm          | 60 cm3
etc
```

Example table from the sheet in question.

```
Second sheet containing data. Note, Item List column can have up to 40 items 
Num | Value | Item list
123 | Solid | ItemA, ItemB, ItemC, 
456 | Liquid| ItemC, ItemA, ItemB
789 | Plasma| ItemB, ItemC, ItemA
```

What I am struggling to achieve is that this new sheet lists out all the 'Num' and 'Value' rows on their own row like so:

```
Item List |Num | Value 
ItemA     | 123| Solid
ItemA     | 456| Liquid
ItemA     | 789| Plasma
```

This is my first 'serious' foray into the world of VBA. I want to thank you all for your assistance ahead of time!

Comment: Your output looks incomplete - please edit the output to be accurate based off the input table you provided

Comment: Do you actually need the first sheet for this? I don't see how that comes into play here.

Comment: Do you only want to document the items that are on the first sheet? I.E. only items A and B? This is why your output should be consistent with the inputs you have shared. Please [edit] your question and make it clear how all 3 tables you have shared are related. Also, you said this is your first `series` foray into VBA. Does that mean you have some **code to share?** Else, *we may have to debate what a serious foray is ;)*

Comment: @Warcupine the first sheet is needed as that is pulling in data from other sheets as well via index/match lookups.

Comment: You'll need to split each item list on "," then lop over the resulting array and write out each elment and its matching ColA/B values to a new sheet.

Comment: Right, but does that actually relate to this task. As @urdearboy said, do you only want Items A and B while C should be ignored?

Comment: @Warcupine Column C from sheet 2 is the 'match'/key between two sheets and cant be ignored/ommited from the output or I wouldnt know what each line will relate to.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have tried with splitting the third column from comma delimited to separate cells using the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61292597/reading-lbr-xml-as-txt-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use a nested loop:

1. Loop through your `Items` on the first sheet
2. Loop through your `Values` on the second sheet (*i.e. Item is present in comma separated list*)
3. Use `InStr` to determine if a `Item` has a associated `Value`
4. If so, dump the output on sheet 3

---

```
Sub SERIOUS_FORAY()

'Declare and set worksheets
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim ws3 As Worksheet: Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

'Declare required variables
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, lr3 As Long
Dim Items As Range, Values As Range

'Determine range for each sheet
lr1 = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = ws2.Range("C" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr3 = ws3.Range("A" & ws3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Nested Loop
For Each Item In ws1.Range("A2:A" & lr1)
    For Each Values In ws2.Range("C2:C" & lr2)
        If InStr(Values, Item) Then
            ws3.Range("A" & lr3 + 1) = Item
            ws3.Range("B" & lr3 + 1) = Values.Offset(0, -2)
            ws3.Range("C" & lr3 + 1) = Values.Offset(0, -1)
                lr3 = lr3 + 1
        End If
    Next Values
Next Item

End Sub
```

---

Given the first 2 tables you provided, this is the output I got on `Sheet3` (*which assumes headers to be present before running*)

[image]

Comment: See - this is why your example needs to match your exact problem. This assumed your first sheet had a `UNIQUE` set of values to loop through. You will have to update that here such that your `Item` loop is a unique set of values - not gonna update since you changed the problem after this was provided. My fault for assuming tho

Comment: You are correct and my edit to the original was in error, the first sheet Item List (Col A) is unique, it is the Item List in Sheet 2 (col C) that has the multiple values. During my edit I made sheet 1 reflect what sheet 3 is going to look like. After the edit I am going to give your solution a shot and report back. Thank you for the awesome work so far!

Comment: You solution worked perfectly. If I could PM you to send you a beer I would. Great work, and thank you again!